# PHP problems when uploading my website?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I made a website on localhost. Then I uploaded it to different servers, and no problem. However, this time I tried to upload the web to another server, and in this one the code, which is exactly the same working on the other sites, does not work well. I was simplifying the mistake and must be in one of the following lines.

If I type on the URL my website, my code has to add the default language to the URL automatically (which is **es**), if this one has not been specified yet. For example, if I type **mydomain.com**, it must be converted to **mydomain.com/es**.

Here the codes (*Note: lang was declared in htaccess, and is the name of the first parameter introduced on the URL, in this case, the language*):

**index.php CODE:**

```
<?php
    $idiomas = array("ES", "GL", "EN");
    if (!(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == "admin")) {
        require_once("pages/language.php");
    }
?>
```

**language.php CODE:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != "") {
        switch ($_GET['lang']) {
            case strtolower($idiomas[0]):
            case strtolower($idiomas[1]):
            case strtolower($idiomas[2]):
            case 'admin':
                $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
                break;
            default: {
                header("Location: ".ROOT);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['lang']) || $_SESSION['lang'] == "") {
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='.strtolower($idiomas[0]).'">';
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

Now, what is happening is: you type **mydomain.com** and this one is converted to **mydomain.com/es** on the URL, right, but it starts to do this each milisecond, reloading and reloading the page forever. I realised that when **mydomain.com/es** is already on the URL, in **language.php** the first condition of the **if** is not kept, and it should be kept.

I do not know why this code always worked in different servers and not in this one. Any idea, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you enabled mod rewrite in apache?

Comment: @ThomasHambach you were right! This server does not have mod_rewrite enabled.

Answer (score 0):

As per your concern , URL is converted to other URL , this might be the reason for your problem as the $_GET['lang'] will not be exist on other converted URL.

Please check .htaccess file in your code directory.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the session handling
You should start with session_start();
also you have to set the "lang" variable when you redirect ...
Another option would be to include in the end of the url the ?lang= parameter (GET method)

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/'.strtolower($idiomas[0]).'?lang='.$idiomas[0].'">';
```